# Calling Web Service from a C# Console application. The website is secure with form Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication, console-application

I have a asp.net MVC 2 website.
I would like to call a web page (http://localhost/main/SendEmail) with a C# Console Application.

Is there a way to do this ?

**In summary** 
1 - C# Application Console  Call A method in the website /main/SendEmail. 
2 - The website is secure with Form authentication 
3 - I don't want to use the anonymous attribute, we need authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

Does the webpage you are calling require an authenticated user? If not, you could allow anonymous access to just that URL in the web.config:

```
<location path="main/SendEmail">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Yeah, it could be a possibility to doing that, but I really need to have this section secure. I need to know how to call the webpage and be authenticated.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.ksingla.net/2006/08/sample_forms_authentication_test_in_csharp/. You need to parse the login page and POST the page with the credentials as if a user was logging in. Then store the cookies to keep using the authenticated session.

Answer (score 0):

So first you have to post your credentials to the login page.  Be sure to record all the cookies from the resultant HttpResponse.   In all subsequent HttpRequests be sure to pass in all the recorded cookies.

That should do it.

Comment: Do you have a link to share with an example?. If you know how to do this, can you paste the code please? Thanks for you help.